# navigation error with Dependency Injection MAUI

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, maui, .net-maui

I am in the process of transforming my entire application to MVVM and adding Dependency
Injection. for the navigation I have used

`Navigation.PushAsync(new date());`

it which worked but now its no longer works. do you have some solutions.

inside date.xaml.cs

```
public partial class date : ContentPage
{
    public date(dateViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
    
    private void GoNav(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

the C# compile error is

> CS7036    There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'vm' of 'date.date(dateViewModel)' dateCalculator (net6.0-android), dateCalculator (net6.0-ios), dateCalculator (net6.0-maccatalyst), dateCalculator (net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0)  C:\Users\source\repos\dateCalculator\dateCalculator\MainPage.xaml.cs   12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Cause

It is because you remove the `default class constructor` and create a new one with parameter, so when you call  `new date()` it can't be able to find the constructor without parameter(the default one) , that's why the error comes.

#### Solution

1. Remove the new constructor .

Or

2. Give the value on the parameter when creating the class .

   ```
   Navigation.PushAsync(new date(YourVm));
   ```