# Dependency injection and passing VIewModel argument via xaml .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, mvvm, arguments, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to pass an argument to my MainPage() constructor via xaml, but I'm getting an error: "Missing default constructor for "MyApp.View.MainPage"

I understand that I'm missing the parameter-less constructor in my MainPage code.

The following page is my root page called from the App class so I can have a flyout menu. Here's the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
            xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"
            xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel"
            x:Class="MyApp.View.FlyoutMenuRoot"
            Title="FlyoutMenuRoot">
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <view:FlyoutMenuPage x:Name="flyoutMenuRoot" />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <view:MainPage>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <viewmodel:MyAppViewModel />
                    </x:Arguments>
                </view:MainPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

I'm pretty sure the `<viewmodel:MyAppViewModel />` line is completely wrong. What can I do to pass MyAppViewModel as an argument to MainPage?

Comment: You need to "register" both the view and the viewmodel in App.xaml.cs. In the method that does app building. Then DI is able to resolve the references, find and use the correct constructor. I don't see a mention of constructor parameters in [Dependency Injection doc / Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#registration). But first step, is to make sure you do what is shown in doc. IIRC, there is an earlier StackOverflow question on this topic, with an answer showing what to do.

Comment: Could you provide some more relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described. By the way, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256543/navigation-error-with-dependency-injection-maui?rq=1), it's about the question of DI.

Comment: I rethought my dependency injection methods and got it working.

Comment: Could you please provide your solution? I got the same inquiry.

Comment: @HoàngTrần Instead of setting the Detail page in XAML, I did it in the code behind of FlyoutMenuRoot.